# espacio blanco en el header

Tags: css, html5, responsive

Reemplace el toggle del menú por la información de contacto; teléfono y mail. Al momento de reemplazarlo, elimine todo lo que tenia que ver con el toggle en el HTML y en style.css pero aun queda el espacio en blanco...

PD. Sólo aparece el espacio en blanco en la responsiva para mobile... cuando está en la pantalla completa, no pasa.

[image: aqui se ve bien para desktop]

[image: ese es el espacio blanco que debo eliminar para que contacto y el logo esten en la misma linea.]

```css
a[href^="mailto"]::before {
    content: " ";
}

a[href^="tel"]::before {
    content: " ";
}

#fh5co-header .navbar {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#fh5co-header #navbar .navbar-right {
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  #fh5co-header #navbar .navbar-right {
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
}
#fh5co-header #navbar li a {
  font-family: "PT Sans", Arial, serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  #fh5co-header #navbar li a {
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    padding-right: 10px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<header role="banner" id="fh5co-header">
  <div class="fluid-container">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

    <div class="navbar-header">
     <!-- Mobile Toggle Menu Button -->
     <a href="https://app.logispak.com/#/signup" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><i></i></a>
     <a href="index.html" ><img src="images/logo-completo-png.png" alt=""></a>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-contact" align="right" >
     <address>
                    <a href="mailto:info@logispak.com">info@logispak.com<br/>
                    <a href="tel:+52-81-3096-6072"> 81 3096 6072</a><br/>
                    </address>
                </div>
   </nav>
   </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: Hola, por favor no publiques versiones de la misma pregunta varias veces. Edita  la pregunta original. Voy a eliminar la otra pregunta, pero lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que lo intentaste solucionar con esta línea:

```
#fh5co-header #navbar .navbar-right {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Y creo que el fallo es la ruta escrita. Intenta con eso y me dices que pasó.

Comment: Sí, ya intenté con margin-right: 0; y aún no funciona. 
Perdón, ¿a qué te refieres con fallo en la ruta escrita?

Comment: Cuando intenté encontrar el elemento del codigo que copie no lo encontré en tu DOM

Comment: ya pude!!!! muchas gracias

Comment: de nada y suerte con tu proyecto :D